# Await on an asynchronous function not resolving before continuing

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a function that looks like this:

```
async function sync(req, res, done){
    await createRecords().then(async ()=> {
        await Promise.all(
            [
                quantityReport(),
                listings(),
                productIdentifiers(),
                productChildren()

        ])
    }).then(async ()=>{
        await saveAll()
    } ).then(await createCSV);
}

module.exports = sync
```

I am calling it like this inside a switch:

```
// const saveRecords = require('../scripts/saveRecords.js') <- for reference

await saveRecords;
```

My problem is that the program continues before saveRecords finishes and I cannot figure out why.

All of the functions in Promise.all are asynchronous functions.

If I call sync() directly in saveRecords.js it works fine.

Thanks.

**edit**

createCSV also works fine in other locations in the program. It's imported to this file like this:

```
const {createCSV, uploadReports} = require('../scripts/createCSV.js')
```

```
//in createCSV.js

module.exports = createCSV;
```

Comment: `then(await createCSV);` — You need to pass a **function** to `then` (this is likely your problem but you haven't supplied a [mcve])

Comment: It is, I'll update the question with the import statement.

Comment: Using `then` with `await` seems like a bit of an anti-pattern.

Comment: [Promises are not just callbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22539815/arent-promises-just-callbacks). Nested `.then()` calls are a code smell. As is `.then(async () =>{/*...*/})`. In general, don't try to mix `await` and `.then`.

Comment: `then( async () => await something_that_returns_a_promise() )` is the nested promise antipattern. It works out to be the same as `then(() => something_that_returns_a_promise())` but with more bloat.

Comment: Why is the name of an `async` function `sync`? o.O

Comment: ha, this syncs data, I guess it could be named better...

Comment: Did you mean `await saveRecords()`? Because in your example you're not calling the function.

Comment: @Andy likely `.then(createCSV);` if `.then()` is to be used.

Comment: adding () to saveRecords seems to be working (program takes around 7 minutes to finish). Why is this? It's exported and imported as above. saveRecords.js exports the sync function.

Comment: Yes. But `await saveRecords;` doesn't _call_ the function.

Answer (score 0):

I'd refactor your function as such (by the way, `sync` doesn't sounds like a great name for your function, write something more obvious).

```js
async function sync(req, res, done){
try{
    await createRecords()
    const _res = await Promise.all([
                quantityReport(),
                listings(),
                productIdentifiers(),
                productChildren()
                ])
    if(_res) {
        await saveAll()
        await createCSV()
    }
    return 
   }
    catch(err){
    throw new Error(err)
  }
}

module.exports = sync
```

Comment: Yes sorry, I wrote too quickly, I was indeed lacking a curlybrace to close the try and the await.

Comment: Is there a reason why you rely on ASI?

Comment: Thanks for the help, but this produces the same result.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comments using [`async/await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await) with [`then` from the Promise API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) (see also [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)) is an odd thing to do. Use one or the other. But the **key** issue is that you're not *calling* the sync function `await sync()`.

Here's an quick example of simply using `async/await`.

```js
function mockCall(n) {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    setTimeout(() => res(n), 1000);
  });
}

async function sync() {

  const first = await mockCall(1);

  const twoToFive = await Promise.all([
    mockCall(2),
    mockCall(3),
    mockCall(4),
    mockCall(5)
  ]);

  const six = await mockCall(6);

  const seven = await mockCall(7);

  console.log([ first, twoToFive, six, seven ]);

}

(async function main() {
  await sync();
  console.log('Let the processing resume!');
})();
```

Comment: I presume you mean `then` instead of `fetch`?